# Use CLAHE in openCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to use CLAHE in openCV Android.

```
CLAHE clahe = new CLAHE(0);
clahe.setClipLimit(0.01);
clahe.setTilesGridSize(new Size(8, 8));
Mat I2 = new Mat();
clahe.apply(I,I2);
```

As you can see I don't know what to put there for the constructor in the first line, so I just put 0 there. And of course it throws run time error. I looked up the official doc and source code:

```
protected CLAHE(long addr) { super(addr); }
```

I still don't know what to put for "addr". Or I'm using this whole CLAHE class in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Imgproc.createCLAHE()`, depending on what version of OpenCV you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using openCV 3.0, there is no Imgproc.createCLAHE(). which version do u have?

Comment: Is this not available?  http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#createCLAHE()

Comment: Not in openCV Android 3.0